# Powershell - Find and Replace

Tags: string, powershell, replace, find

I've written the below:

```
$Path = "C:\"
$Folders = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where-Object {$_.mode -match "d"}

$FolderName = @()
$Folders | ForEach-Object { $FolderName += $_.name }

ForEach ($Name in $FolderName) {

$File = "C:\$Name\file.xaml"
$Content = Get-Content $File

$A = "ValueA"
$B = "ValueB"
$C = "ValueC"
$D = "ValueD"

$Content | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace $A, $B} | Set-Content $File
$Content | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace $C, $D} | Set-Content $File

}
```

However, the first find and replace does not work. I thought it was because the actual string I'm looking for is quite large, but if I change nothing in the program and then comment out the second find and replace operation, the first one starts to work. Can anyone spot why this is please? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your issue is not that the values overlap eachother your are writing the same source content back to file. You should combine  the two `Set-Content` lines.

```
$Content | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace $A, $B -Replace $C, $D} | Set-Content $File
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh `$Content` before doing the second find and replace. At the moment, you're setting the content of the file in the first call to `Set-Content`, but the variable `$Content` still contains the old contents of the file. If you call `$Content = Get-Content $File` again before doing the second call, you should be golden.

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense!